# What is the Location of Safari Default Bookmark/Preference list?

Tags: ios, macos, safari, osx-elcapitan

Im trying to figure out where the default bookmarks of Safari live, because i want to change the bookmarks so I can deploy it out to other users. Does anyone know where any .plist or file is located that contains the default bookmarks/home page?

Not the plist in the user library. It has to be in the app contents or such places that way it can be changed and pushed out to network users before they are created.

Question is - Where is the Safari **Default** bookmark/preferences located?

Thank you for any information you have to offer.

Answer (score 2):

/Users/Bilbo/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist

I've done a lot of searching but it seems theres no plist or a file that contains the bookmarks, when you launch Safari for the first time it fetches bookmarks from somewhere else and deposits a plist in the user folder. My workaround is in another answer to another one of my own questions.

Summary: Basically a LaunchAgent that will add my own Bookmarks.plist to my user file before the user ever launches Safari for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/BuiltInBookmarks_en.plist is the file that contains the default bookmarks